# Scrape multiple JavaScript-based websites in R

Tags: javascript, r, loops, web-scraping, phantomjs

These are my first steps in programming and I'm trying to learn as much as I can before bothering you guys. But right now I'm pretty much stuck after trying several ways (thought of by myself or found online).

What I'm trying to do now is saving multiple whole JavaScript pages to further work with them in R. As far as I understood this is just possible using phantomjs. I've managed to get a code loading the page. But I'm struggling with the loop:

```
       writeLines("var page = new WebPage();
       var fs = require('fs');


       for (i = 101; i <= 150; i++) {
       page.open('http://understat.com/match/' + i, function (status) {
               just_wait();
       });


       function just_wait() {
           setTimeout(function() {
           fs.write('match' + i + '.html', page.content, 'w');
        phantom.exit();
           }, 2500);
       }
       }
       ", con = "scrape.js")

       js_scrape <- function(
                  js_path = "scrape.js", 
                  phantompath = "/Users/Marek/Documents/Programmierung/Startversuche/phantomjs-2.1.1/bin/phantomjs"){

                    lines <- readLines(js_path)
                    command = paste(phantompath, js_path, sep = " ")
                    system(command)

                  }

       js_scrape()
```

It's just saving the last page of the loop. Reading other threads I understood that the problem is that phantomJS is asynchronous and is pretty much closing the pages before they have been loaded. But I could not work a way around, so it's saving all of the pages in different files.